# Entity framework on updating model giving an error

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am trying to update the model by selecting a newly added stored procedure, till now I have added with out any issues but when I am adding the one which is newly created I am getting an error as attached

[image]

Can some one help me. If i remove all the code inside stored procedure and adding then it is adding to the model but not with the code I want

Comment: Show the stored procedure.

Comment: Resolved by creating an empty procedure first and then adding the required and updating the model